# Automatically Set DeployChangesExecutionOrder

Tags: readyroll

Is there a way to automatically set the Deployment Order based on dependancy (DeployChangesExecutionOrder)? Seems like this is something that should be automatically done upon project import?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using RedGate "Sql Dependency Tracker" to export a xml file with dependencies and then wrote some custom code to reorder the items under the "DeployChangesExecutionOrder" node based on that. Hopefully the tooling will get better in the future to save people time.

Comment: Great tip. I agree that the process of setting the deployment order ought to be done automatically. Perhaps you could add your vote/voice to this product suggestion if you have a moment?
https://readyroll.uservoice.com/forums/204125-readyroll-product-feedback/suggestions/16895878-automatically-order-programmable-objects-by-their